# why does browser still refused to load the image base64 after I added the Content-Security-Policy mate

Tags: reactjs, browser, create-react-app, content-security-policy

i created a new project with the create-react-app and  browser still refused to load the image base64  after I added the Content-Security-Policy mate

**index.html**

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data: ;"/>`

**console**

`` Refused to load the image 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEwAVAMQAAOLx9cro7t3v89zu89bt8dXt8d/v89Ps8ODw9NLr8Nru88vo79ft8dnu8s/q79Hr783q787q78vp78nn7szp78no7gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAATABUAAAVvICCOZGmeqIisbOu2RizP9CzceK7nQ+//wJ9iSCwai42kcslcMp7QqDRKqFqv2Gthy+16u4eweEweJ87otDr9aLvf8LdjTq/b65G8fs/fQ/6AgYKBEoWGh4UUiBILjY6PkI8Bk5SVkxWWlBOZnJQhADs=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src *". Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. data:' must be added explicitely. ``

[err msg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGyoA.png)

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Your meta CSP is not taken by the browser. Is there another defined in your apache/nginx configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy you show is "img-src 'self' data: ;" while the the violated directive given in the error message is "img-src *". This means that there are multiple policies, and content needs to pass all policies. It does pass the one defined in your meta tag, but there is likely another policy set in a response header that you will also need to remove or modify to allow "data:".

Comment: its useful, I find another policy in the Apache config file. thank you